# Having problems with Membership Login expiring and use of Ajax.ActionLink, login page appears in Ajax return area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, C#, Razor, Ajax

I have implemented an Ajax.Actionlink. All works well.

However, since I am also using Membership Services, I will get logged out of the system if I do not use it for say 20 mins. If one is on the Ajax page, and one clicks an Ajax link, the Ajax returns, within the TargetDiv, the Login page and not the correct partial view.

I suspect that if the app has expired then the response needs to override the ajax response, and return the full login page.

How can I solve this please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom authorize attribute to handle the situation.

```
public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            response.StatusCode = 590; //custom status code, might as well be 401, dont know if that would violate any proncipal
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

add some js codes in master page to handle the custom status code.

```
$(function () {
    return $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        if (590 == xhr.status) {
            return document.location = document.location;
        }
    });
});
```

use it as any `[Authorize]` attribute for the ajax actions you like to be authorized

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AjaxAuthorize]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod()
    {
        return Json(new {message = "Hello"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

1. The custom Authorize filter will handle the unauthorized request and issue an empty
   result with status code 590
2. The response will be caught as ajaxerror since the statuscode is 5**
3. The document will be reloaded (assuming the page is an authenticated one), as such will be redirected to login page.

Hope this helps

Comment: Gosh, what a reply. Huge thanks. Will test now.. Do not think I would have got there...